# Laravel 10 to 11: Call to undefined method ReflectionFunction::isAnonymous()

Tags: laravel

I recently upgraded my Laravel application from version 10 to 11, and I've encountered a runtime error that I'm unable to resolve. The error message is as follows:

```
Call to undefined method ReflectionFunction::isAnonymous() at 
/var/www/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:680
```

This issue appears immediately after upgrading to Laravel 11, and disappears when I revert back to Laravel 10. Here are some key details about my environment and the upgrade process:

PHP Version: 8.3.1

```
Symfony components upgraded from v6.4.x to v7.0.x 
nunomaduro/termwind from v1.15.1 to v2.0.1 
symfony/clock from not present to v7.0.5 
carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types from 2.1.0 to 3.2.0 
nesbot/carbon from 2.72.3 to 3.1.1 
laravel/framework from v10.43.0 to v11.0.6 
staudenmeir/belongs-to-through from v2.15.1 to v2.16
```

Laravel Upgrade: from version 10 to 11
Composer Update Changes:

And other Symfony component upgrades as part of the Laravel 11 upgrade requirements.
Given that PHP 8.3 should support the ReflectionFunction::isAnonymous() method, I'm puzzled about the source of this error. Before posting here, I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Checked the PHP version (CLI and web server) to confirm it's 8.3.1.
Cleared Laravel's cache (config, cache, and view).
Ran composer update to ensure all dependencies are up to date.
Verified that all required PHP extensions for Laravel 11 are installed and enabled.

I'm looking for insights or suggestions on how to fix this error. Could it be related to a specific package upgrade, or is there something else I'm missing in the Laravel 11 upgrade process?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If this happened after a upgrade where you haven't changed any of your own code, you should check whether this is a bug in Laravel

Comment: I have experienced that some packages run better with 8.2, especially when changing packages with composer

Comment: And share the stack trace, so we see when was the last point on your code and then purely framework code (also share your last line of code executed)

Comment: what is the output of `php -v`? You say you are using 8.3 but I think your CLI might be using a different version

Answer (score 0):

change cli php version, i had the same error when running it with cli 8.1 on my hosting provider.

see which version by running `php -v`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with a brand new project and made it work using php version 8.2.16-fpm-alpine.

Comment: From the original post: "PHP Version: 8.3.1" - what makes you think that downgrading to an older version of PHP resolves the problem?

Comment: Well as I said, I had that same issue using version 8.3 and it was solved by downgrading to 8.2, which was also suggested by another user. I don't have enough experience with PHP to know what or why, just telling my experience.

Answer (score -1):

The function [ReflectionFunction::isAnonymous](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunction.isanonymous.php) was added in php 8.2. I got the same error when running an older webserver PHP version. (Currently running on 8.3.3 without error)

Comment: If the OP is **really** using PHP 8.3.1, your answer does not help to resolve the problem

Answer (score -3):

It helps sometimes if you import methods again by hand, but not for all methods..

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Which method should be imported, and how could that resolve the given error message?